# CompositeDataBoundControl - databound values overwritten before event is fired due to DummyDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

I have a custom servercontrol that inherits from CompositeDataBoundControl. I have three templates: one header template, one footer template and one item template. The item template can contain a checkbox that I use to decide if I should delete the item.

In the footer and/or header templates I have a button with a CommandName of "DeleteItem". When that button is clicked, I handle the event in OnBubbleEvent:

```
if (cea.CommandName == "DeleteItem") {
    //loop through the item list and get the selected rows
    List<int> itemsToDelete = new List<int>();
    foreach(Control c in this.Controls){
        if (c is ItemData) {
            ItemData oid = (ItemData)c;
            CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)oid.FindControl("chkSelected");
            if (chkSel.Checked) {
                itemsToDelete.Add(oid.Item.Id);
            }
        }                        
    }
    foreach (int id in itemsToDelete) {
        DeleteItem(id);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that **Item** is null since the CreateChildControls method already has been run as asp.net needs to recreate the control hierarchy before the event fire. It uses the DummyDataSource and a list of null objects to recreate the control hierarchy:

```
IEnumerator e = dataSource.GetEnumerator();
if (e != null) {
while (e.MoveNext()) {
    ItemData container = new ItemData (e.Current as OrderItem);
    ITemplate itemTemplate = this.ItemTemplate;
    if (itemTemplate == null) {
        itemTemplate = new DefaultItemTemplate();
    }
    itemTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
    Controls.Add(container);
    if (dataBinding) {
        container.DataBind();
    }
    counter++;
}
```

}

The problem is this line:  **ItemData container = new ItemData (e.Current as OrderItem);** When the control hierarchy is rebuilt before the event is fired, the e.Current is null, so when I try to find out which item was marked for deletion, I get 0 since the original value has been overwritten.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution that works. The problem is that the bound data is only connected to the control when being bound and directly after(normally accessed in a ItemDataBound event).

So to solve it I had to add a hidden literal containing the data item id to the container control. In the OnBubbleEvent I find the hidden literal and get the id:

```
ItemData oid = (ItemData)c;
CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)oid.FindControl("chkSelected");
if(chkSel != null) {
      if(chkSel.Checked) {
         Literal litId = (Literal)oid.FindControl("litId");
         itemsToDelete.Add(Utils.GetIntegerOnly(litId.Text));
      }
}
```